# WPF Explicitly using styles for all TabItems in my Panel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a window with a TabControl, all TabItems in this TabControl should have the same style:

```
<TabControl Name="TabControl1">
    <TabControl.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="TabItem">...</Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>

    <TabItem Header="Tab Item 1"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab Item 2"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab Item 3"/>
</TabControl>
```

Of course this works as expected.

I want several TabItems in my application to have this style. Some other TabItems in other TabControls should have a different style. So I created several styles in App.XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyle1" TargetType="TabItem">...</Style>
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyle2" TargetType="TabItem">...</Style>
```

Now I have to specify that all TabItems in my TabControl1 should use TabItemStyle1.

```
<TabControl Name="Example2">
    <TabItem Header="Tab Item 1" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1}" />
    <TabItem Header="Tab Item 2" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1}"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab Item 3" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1}"/>
</TabControl>
```

This works, but I'd rather define that all the TabItems in TabControl1 should use the TabItemStyle1.

```
<TabControl Name="Example3">
    <TabControl.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="TabItem"        ???
    </TabControl.Resources>

    <TabItem Header="Tab Item 1"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab Item 2"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab Item 3"/>
</TabControl>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new implicit style scoped to the tabcontrol and inheriting TabItemStyle1.

```
<TabControl Name="Example3">
    <TabControl.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1}"/>
    </TabControl.Resources>
```

( The above is air code, I've not checked exact syntax in an app ).

Comment: This works, but in fact I am creating a new style, am I not?

Comment: It does. But you can't set a style on something from it's own style.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ItemContainerStyle` of `TabControl`, that will apply the style to all `TabItem`s.

```
<TabControl>
   <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
         <!-- ...your setters. -->
      </Style>
   </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
   <TabItem Header="Tab Item 1"/>
   <TabItem Header="Tab Item 2"/>
   <TabItem Header="Tab Item 3"/>
</TabControl>
```

You can of course also reference them if they are defined elsewhere, like in `App.xaml`:

```
<TabControl ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1}">
```

Both samples apply the style only to the `TabItems` within the associated `TabControl`. If you want these styles to be applied to all `TabItem`s within other **nested** `TabControl`s, then you have to create an implicit style scoped to the `TabControl`, as @Andy suggested.

```
<TabControl>
   <TabControl.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
         <!-- ...your setters. -->
      </Style>
   </TabControl.Resources>
   <TabItem Header="Tab Item 1">
      <TabControl>
         <TabItem Header="Nested tab Item 1"/>
         <TabItem Header="Nested tab Item 2"/>
         <TabItem Header="Nested tab Item 3"/>
      </TabControl>
   </TabItem>
   <TabItem Header="Tab Item 2"/>
   <TabItem Header="Tab Item 3"/>
</TabControl>
```